# String formatting difference with list and tuple

Tags: python

## What is the difference in below statements:

```
exam_st_date = (11,12,2014)

print( "The examination will start from : %i / %i / %i"%exam_st_date)
```

When  i execute  this python statement i get output: The examination will start from : 11 / 12 / 2014

But if i change exam_st_date = (11,12,2014)  to

```
exam_st_date = [11,12,2014]
```

as a list format

and if i execute same statement again  then i gets error

```
C:\Users\bambored>python C:\Python\examdate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\examdate.py", line 6, in <module>
    print('The examination will start from : %i / %i / %i'%exam_st_date)
TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not list
```

Comment: It's to do with how Python groups everything together. Think of a tuple as a gang of friends in a line and a list as a group of people handcuffed together. The list is technically just one thing while the tuple here is 3.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the `format` method https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax instead, it will work with both types and IMO feels more idiomatic than printf style formatting. For this example it may be `"The examination will start from : {} {} {}".format(*exam_date)` which also takes advantage of tuple/list unpacking.

Answer (score 4):

you are getting a TypeError. It means that the variable you are passing to your print function is not of the required type. You are asked to pass an integer and not a list.
Python is treating the list you created as one single object and not as 3 integers.

In your working example, you are using a tuple, which is recognized as 3 integer variables.